Otp.NET Verification Window not understandable
I've a problem with Otp.NET lib for TOTP generation/verification.
Due to some reasons I've a requirement where I need to generate totp codes valid up to some days.
But following test code does not work:
using OtpNet;
using System;

// Secret key for TOTP (must be consistent across all tests)
byte[] secretKey = Base32Encoding.ToBytes("JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP");

// Create a Totp instance with an optional time offset
Totp totpGenerator = new Totp(secretKey);

// Simulate generating TOTP at different dates
DateTime generationTime = DateTime.Now;
string totpCode = totpGenerator.ComputeTotp(generationTime);
Console.WriteLine($"TOTP generated on {generationTime}: {totpCode}");

TestTotpValidity(totpCode, generationTime.AddDays(5)); // 5 days later. this should be valid but is invalid.

TestTotpValidity(totpCode, generationTime.AddDays(-5)); // 5 days earlier. this should be not valid but is valid.

TestTotpValidity(totpCode, generationTime.AddDays(7));  // 7 days later. this should be valid but is invalid.
TestTotpValidity(totpCode, generationTime.AddDays(-7));  // 7 days earlier. this should be not valid but is valid.

TestTotpValidity(totpCode, generationTime.AddDays(8));  // 8 days later. This should be invalid and is invalid.
TestTotpValidity(totpCode, generationTime.AddDays(-8));  // 8 days earlier. this should be not valid and is invalid.

void TestTotpValidity(string totpCode, DateTime verificationTime)
{
    var validator = new Totp(secretKey);
    long timeStepMatched;
    bool isValid = validator.VerifyTotp(verificationTime, totpCode, out timeStepMatched, new VerificationWindow(previous: 2, future: 2880 * 7)); // Custom verification window. 2880 steps / day -> 4 days

    Console.ForegroundColor = isValid ? ConsoleColor.DarkGreen : ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.WriteLine($"Verifying TOTP on {verificationTime} (time step matched {timeStepMatched}): {isValid}");
    Console.ResetColor();
}

This is the console output:
TOTP generated on 05/16/2024 10:08:22: 935002
39;49mVerifying TOTP on 05/21/2024 10:08:22 (time step matched 0): False
[39;49m[39;49mVerifying TOTP on 05/11/2024 10:08:22 (time step matched 57195136): True
[39;49m[39;49mVerifying TOTP on 05/23/2024 10:08:22 (time step matched 0): False
[39;49m[39;49mVerifying TOTP on 05/09/2024 10:08:22 (time step matched 57195136): True
[39;49m[39;49mVerifying TOTP on 05/24/2024 10:08:22 (time step matched 0): False
[39;49m[39;49mVerifying TOTP on 05/08/2024 10:08:22 (time step matched 0): False
[39;49m

I'm not understanding something from their doc or am I doing something wrong?
Please, some help about this would be worth.
Here you have dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A1dOEm
Edit: Now instances for generation and each validation are different so should be valid anytime. I want to accept only once but I would like to test that validation window is well defined. In this example, TOTP code generated today should be valid until 7 days ahead if I don't misunderstood something from documentation.

You understood the "One-Time" part of TOTP? Please tell us the reasoning why you need a token that is designed to be used once to be valid for such a long time. In your example the second validation should always fail ignoring any validity timespan as it has been already validated once. After that it should be invalid.

You were right. Sample updated. Now instances for generation and each validation are different so should be valid anytime I would say. I want to accept only once but I would like to test that validation window is well defined. In this example, TOTP code generated today should be valid until 7 days ahead if I don't misunderstood something from documentation.

The validity timeframe is actually meant to cope with asynchronous clocks between the generator of the token and the one validating it. That validity window goes therefore in both direction because you can't predict how asynchron those clocks are. For Otp.Net (i don't know that library) its presumably hidden in the VerificationWindow parameter. As there a two times(creation,validation) here there might be a problem what previous/future means here. Maybe they are meant the other way round?

For example i could interpret it now as "The generator clock is allowed to be 7 days in the future compared to my verification systems clock".

First of all, thanks to ralf comment above which is key.

As there a two times(creation,validation) here there might be a problem what previous/future means here.

Here you can find corrected fiddle with corrected VerificationWindow.
It was the opposite I understood before.
If you want your code to be valid from now to 7 days ahead, VerificationWindow must be 7 days past, not 7 days future.
using System;
using OtpNet;

byte[] secretKey = Base32Encoding.ToBytes("JBSWY3DPEHPK3PXP");
Totp totpGenerator = new Totp(secretKey);

// Generate TOTP code using the current time
DateTime generationTime = DateTime.Now;
string totpCode = totpGenerator.ComputeTotp();
Console.WriteLine($"TOTP generated on {generationTime}: {totpCode}");

// Test the validity of the TOTP code from 7 days in the past to 9 days in the future
for (var days = -7; days < 10; days++)
{
    TestTotpValidity(totpCode, generationTime.AddDays(days));
}

void TestTotpValidity(string totpCode, DateTime verificationTime)
{
    var validator = new Totp(secretKey);
    long timeStepMatched;
    
    // 2880 steps per day, window of 7 days in the past and 2 steps in the future
    bool isValid = validator.VerifyTotp(verificationTime, totpCode, out timeStepMatched, new VerificationWindow(previous: 2880 * 7, future: 2));
    Console.WriteLine($"Verifying TOTP on {verificationTime} (time step matched {timeStepMatched}): {isValid}");
}

TOTP generated on 05/16/2024 12:38:52: 065465
Verifying TOTP on 05/09/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False
Verifying TOTP on 05/10/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False
Verifying TOTP on 05/11/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False
Verifying TOTP on 05/12/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False
Verifying TOTP on 05/13/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False
Verifying TOTP on 05/14/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False
Verifying TOTP on 05/15/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False
Verifying TOTP on 05/16/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 57195437): True
Verifying TOTP on 05/17/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 57195437): True
Verifying TOTP on 05/18/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 57195437): True
Verifying TOTP on 05/19/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 57195437): True
Verifying TOTP on 05/20/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 57195437): True
Verifying TOTP on 05/21/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 57195437): True
Verifying TOTP on 05/22/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 57195437): True
Verifying TOTP on 05/23/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 57195437): True
Verifying TOTP on 05/24/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False
Verifying TOTP on 05/25/2024 12:38:52 (time step matched 0): False

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7frFel
